# How to instantiate class in Kotlin, if the class is parameter of function?

Tags: kotlin

Im trying to make universal function in Kotlin, which can instantiate every time different  model classes.
Class type is a parameter, to make instance from that class and fill it with data from Json object.

```
fun<T> foo() {
    var myModel = T()
    myModel.id = 2
    myModel.name = ""
}
```

Answer (score 8):

You can use an [`inline reified`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/inline-functions.html) function in combination with an interface.

With `reified` you can access the real class of the generic type parameter.
You still not allowed to call the constructor directly, but reflection will work.

To assign the `id` and `name`, you need to define an interface, that all of your model classes are required to implement:

```
interface Model {
    var id: Int?
    var name: String?
}

inline fun <reified T : Model> createModel() : T {
    val myModel = T::class.createInstance()
    myModel.id = 2
    myModel.name = ""
    return myModel
}
```

A simple example:

```
class TestModel() :  Model {
    override var id: Int? = null
    override var name: String? = null
}

fun main() {
    val model: TestModel = createModel()
}
```

Comment: What if class has no no-arg constructor?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use T definition itself, pass class to the function instead.

```
import kotlin.reflect.KClass

open class Model {
    var id: Int? = null
    var name: String? = null
    fun say() {
        println("hello.")
    }
}
class MyModel: Model()

fun<T: Model> foo(type: KClass<T>): T {
    val myModel = type.java.newInstance()
    myModel.id = 2
    myModel.name = ""
    return myModel
}

val mymodel = foo(MyModel::class)
mymodel.say() // hello.
```

Comment: This the "java" way. In Kotlin, we would rather use an inline function with reified type parameter as mentioned by @Rene

Comment: Thx! You and @Rene also help me.